# Change color of select items on Click in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

[image]I want this result from recyclerview in my project, here 3 different text views and when i select any text view then change its background.

```
holder.llAns1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        holder.llAns1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.que_correct_back);
        holder.llAns2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);holder.llAns3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);   
        allAns.add(holder.tvans1.getText().toString());
        correctans = userlist.get(position).get("correctans");

         /*
         check if selected option is correct
         * */
        if(holder.tvans1.getText().toString().equals(correctans)){
            CorrectAns.add(userlist.get(position).get("ans1"));
        } else {

                try {
                        CorrectAns.remove(position);
                        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                    }

                }
    }); 


holder.llAns2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        holder.llAns2.setTag(position);

        holder.llAns2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.que_correct_back);
        holder.llAns1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
        holder.llAns3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);correctans = userlist.get(position).get("correctans");

        /*
        check if selected option is correct
        * */
        if(holder.tvans2.getText().equals(correctans)){
            CorrectAns.add(userlist.get(position).get("ans2"));
            Log.d("corrAns1",String.valueOf(CorrectAns));

        } else {
                try {
                        CorrectAns.remove(correctans);
                    }
                    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
                        Log.d("corrAns2",String.valueOf(CorrectAns));
                    }
                }
    }); 

holder.llAns3.setTag(position);

holder.llAns3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        holder.llAns3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.que_correct_back); /*set drawable if correct option is selected*/
        holder.llAns2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
        holder.llAns1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);

        correctans = userlist.get(position).get("correctans");

         /*
         check if selected option is correct
         * */

        if(holder.tvans3.getText().equals(correctans)){
            CorrectAns.add(userlist.get(position).get("ans3"));
            Log.d("corrAns1",String.valueOf(CorrectAns));

        }else {
            try {
                CorrectAns.remove(correctans);}catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
            Log.d("corrAns2",String.valueOf(CorrectAns));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: please check the image in my question

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: You can't expect answers without you even trying.

Comment: we are here to help with code not here to write code for you man...

Comment: check code @Moudiz

Comment: check code @oguzhand

Comment: check code @androidnoobdev

Comment: check @SrikarReddy

Answer (score 0):

To implement such Ui and functionality you can use viewpager instead of recycler view with a view (Item view) which display single question and answer every time and when user pick answer (store full model) store in Arraylist. in View pager you can swap views also from code using **setCurrentItem()**. After all that question and all, you can display result in new activity or fragment.

Comment: any demo of recycler view with view pager